# The elusive graviton particle. Why does Hadron colider fail to find this elusive particle. It does exist but i think method for finding it is wrong

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-gravity, large-hadron-collider, hadron-dynamics

Why does Hadron colider fail to find this elusive particle. It does exist but i think method for finding it is floored.i think that trying to find it by collision is a floored method. My theory is this. if they realign the colider to make to paticles miss each other at a sub atomic length so they pass by each other. the force will tear the particles rather then smash them.

Comment: *i think method for finding it is floored.* Do you mean “flawed”?

Comment: What did you read or watch that made you think the LHC should have detected gravitons?

Answer (score 1):

The hadron collider is not suited for detecting gravitons. Moreover, theory predicts it is likely impossible with any device to detect single gravitons.

Quoted from [Wikipedia - Graviton -Experimental observation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton#Experimental_observation):

> Unambiguous detection of individual gravitons, though not prohibited by any fundamental law, is impossible with any physically reasonable detector.